# What exactly does "CSS selector" mean?

Tags: html, css

I'm solving some questions to a job and I'm not sure of the meaning of the CSS selector.

I explain: they gave me a webpage and told me to change the color of the background of a section.

Ok, I did it, but there is a question where I should tell what was the selector that I used and I don't understand what they mean by this.

Can someone help me to understand what is the selector of that part?

[image: The part I changed]

Comment: you didn't use any selector, you used inline style

Comment: You didn’t use a selector because you used inline CSS (`style=`). A selector would be within a style tag or separate CSS file and selects the elements you want to style, e.g. `h1`, `div.class`, #uniqueID

Comment: MDN is a great resource for questions like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors. Agree with others here that you need to add the change to the proper Class in the DOM to show you know how CSS works. I'd say add your own selector to that container, don't style those bootstrap classes.

Comment: So how can i do this (change the background color) using a selector?

Comment: You can inject a piece of code into `<style></style>` tag of the website contents or just use the tab `Styles` in that inspector (right hand side of your screenshot) and create a new rule.

Comment: As far as i noticed the "css selector" should be the "path" (not really this i know) of the section im editing? So the selector of that part woul be: .container div.row div.col-lg-8.col-md-10.mx-auto - does it makes sense?

Comment: Always include your code as code, not an image. We can't copy and paste code from an image. Better still provide a [mcve] using StackSnippets.

Answer (score 3):

A selector in CSS is the context of *how* you select part of a page to style. There are numerous ways to select text.

```
selector
{
 property: value;
 property: value;
}
```

If you want to change the `background-color` of a `p` (paragraph) element you might ask:

- Are other paragraphs going to use a different `background-color`?
- If so is this paragraph a child of the `main` element or a child of an `aside` element.

If all paragraphs are to be the same `background-color` then you'd use a very simple selector: `p`, example:

```
p {background-color: #f00;}
```

If you need to *select* paragraphs that are *only* child elements of the `main` element then you can't use a universal `p` selector blindly, you'd use:

```
aside p {background-color: #00f;}
main p {background-color: #f00;}
```

If you need to *only* change the `background-color` of the third paragraph of the `aside` element you would need to be even more specific in how you *select* what will be styled, here is an example of using [nth selectors](https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/):

```
aside p:nth-of-type(3) {background-color: #0f0;}
```

You can put CSS in multiple places. If you use `<p style="">...</p>` that is an *inline style* and thus there are *no selectors*. CSS is either typically stored in a `styles.css` file (must have a `.css` file extension) or put in to a `<style type="text/css"></style>` element (a child element of the `head` element if you're coding cleanly).

You will also need to understand that you're dealing with CSS, *Cascading* Style Sheets. The further *down* the rule the more likely it will be applied. In example if you use the same rule three times then the example below will make *all* paragraphs of the `main` element have a `background-color` set to `#00f` as it is the last declaration:

```
main p {background-color: #f00;}
main p {background-color: #0f0;}
main p {background-color: #00f;}
```

Since you can select the same element different ways some selectors may be more specific and thus override a selector further down in the CSS code. There is also the use of `!important`. In this next example the `background-color` will be set to `#f00`:

```
main p {background-color: #f00 !important;}
main p {background-color: #0f0;}
main p {background-color: #00f;}
```

I'd recommend reading about all the stuff in CSS at [MDN (Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) and familiarizing yourself with the wonderful plethora of options available via a [CSS selectors test](https://css4-selectors.com/browser-selector-test/).

This is all ridiculously easy stuff and you just need to keep reading. Persistence is the primary path to success! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

> In CSS, selectors are patterns used to select the element(s) you want
>   to style.

In other words `style` attribute of an HTML tag is inline styling. You don't need selectors for inline styling as you're applying it directly and only per single tag.

CSS is a 'sheet' that takes that styling and separates it from the HTML code *(cascade style sheets)*. What it does is, it binds styling with particular element, and it does that by using **selectors**. Not digging too deep into details, theoretically any HTML attribute can be a selector, but most commonly used are: tag name, class, id, combination of those, and some patterns.

You can see tab 'Styles' on the right hand side of your screenshot, there are all 
 styling rules applied to a selected element, from inline at the very top to those coming from CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So if i changed the bg color on the css and put all the "path" to that place is this the selector? For example: .container div.row div.col-lg-8.col-md-10.mx-auto

Comment: @RenatoAbreu Yes, that "path" is all selectors. In the web browser inspector you will see "block rules" and each block will consist of a selector or selectors, opening bracket, styling rules and a closing bracket. You can learn more about css selectors and styling itself [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/).